# usage of future perfect

Tags: tenses

If I am not mistaken one of the keywords for this tense is "by".
e.g By august I will have done my work. But lately, I have found this example: In August Gordon will have been at this company for 25 years. Is it correct to say "In August" ? Shouldn't it be By August?

Comment: *... one of the keywords for this tense is "by"* -- what is the source for this?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, because neither is necessary.

Compare the statement *I will have been alive 60 years.* This makes sense, but you'd tend to wonder when this event will occur, because future perfect can be at any point ***after now***. 
To help your audience understand *when*, you need a subordinate clause indicating *when*, *during*, or something semantically equivalent to those two.  This is where we get additions like *In August* and *By August*.

*In* helps establish *when* this will happen by giving us the time frame of August 1 - August 31. *By* helps establish *when* this will happen by restricting the time frame implied by future perfect tense (that time frame being ***after now***) to after now, but before this other event. So we essentially have *in* meaning between day 1 and day 31, and *by* meaning between today and August 1.

You can use either, it just depends on what you want to communicate - *by* gives us *up until this point*, whereas *in* gives us *between these two points*.